# JavaScript set all column checkboxes in table with +200 rows, but only visible rows on screen are available

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to add toggle buttons for un- and checking checkboxes to a page with a table which is delivered by another system. The table can have more then 200+ rows.

The problem I'm currently facing is, that I can only set the checked properties of the checkbox that are currently visible on the screen. So when I try to use `document.getElementById` for a checkbox which is not on my screen, I got as return value undefined.

Is there a way to load the full content of the table to DOM and not if you scroll to that section in the table?

Update: Sorry for the missing information.

I need to customize a wizard which is rendering a JCA table on the page. I don't have any chance to modify the table itself before generation. Therefore, I need to a script to toggle the checkboxes within the table with a button. The table contains of a few columns with checkboxes. This is the script I'm currently using:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
  if (checkbox != undefined) {
    if (!checkbox.disabled) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
        checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event("change" {bubbles: true}));
    }
 }
```

I know the syntax of the checkboxIds, but when I try to get with `document.getElementById(checkboxId)` the checkbox, then I only get the ones which are visible on the screen. So I can't do the toggle for all checkbox elements in the table.

I'm pretty new in JavaScript, so I don't know what information to provide :)

Update: This is how it looks like in the debugger

```
<div class="x-grid3-row  x-grid3-row-selected" style="width: 1833.71px; height: 22px;"> <!-- WORKING FINE -->
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 1833.71px; height: 22px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-column1" style="width:40.19444444444444px;" tabindex="-1">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-column1">
<input id="SomeID_checkbox_column1" type="checkbox" name="someName" disabled="" ext:qtip="demo">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="x-grid3-row   " style="width: 1833.71px; height: 22px;"></div> <!-- PROBLEM: DIV is not possible to expand and get the checkbox unless the checkbox is visible on screen -->
```

Comment: well if it is lazy loading/paging than we have no clue what it is because we do not know what code you are using.

Comment: You should provide more details about environment/stack you using

Comment: Couldn't you keep a local variable that is `selectAll: true` (or something similar), and if the checkbox for selectAll is true, you handle that on the server? No need to GET all data if the toggle all checkbox is selected.

Comment: It is also possible to toggle just some selected rows and additionally users should be able to see the checked checkboxes in case of scrolling on the table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `getElementsByTagName('input')` if all the `input` html tags are checkbox you could try to get them by Tag insead of ID or Class, I don't know if it will work but you could try...

Also you could try to do the same with JQuery `var checkBoxs = $('input')` then disable the checkboxs iterating over the array.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working, the problem is that I only get the checkboxes which are visible on the browser screen. All other checkboxes are in DIVs, so I don't get them. See above I updated the question